# Append Custom Tags in Swagger.yaml using swagger-maven plugin

Tags: maven, spring-boot, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swagger-maven-plugin

I am using swagger-maven plugin to generate swagger.yaml for a spring boot 2 application. The plugin works fine for the default feilds like info, description,vender extension etc.

However, I need to append some custom yaml to the generated swagger.yaml. ex:

> X-client-integration 
>       Name:test
>   Package: test package
>    Catalogs: 
>         -id: x
>          Seq:1
>         -id:y
>           Seq:2

This appended yaml can be hard coded or copied from a file from a project.

Is there any way to achieve this?